# return data from nodejs mysql connection function

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am doing this:

```
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var config = require('./../Config.js');

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: config.databaseConnection.host ,
        user: config.databaseConnection.user,
        password: config.databaseConnection.password,
        database: config.databaseConnection.database
    });

    var executeQuery = function (querystring) {



connection.connect(function (err) {

    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("connected to database successfully");
    connection.query(querystring,function(err,rows){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(rows);
    });

});

    }


    module.exports = connection;
```

I want data in "rows" to be returned by my fucntion executeQuery. I did a lot of searching on callbacks but could not understand how things are working. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback function to `executeQuery` function. Something like below

```
var executeQuery = function (querystring, myCallbackFunction) {
  connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("connected to database successfully");
    connection.query(querystring, function (err, rows) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(rows);
      myCallbackFunction(rows);
    });
  });
}

const myCallbackFunction = function(rows) {
  // do stuff here with rows
}

executeQuery(querystring, myCallbackFunction)
```

You can also take promise based approach

```
var executeQuery = function (querystring) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.connect(function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("connected to database successfully");
      connection.query(querystring, function (err, rows) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(rows);
        resolve(rown);
      });
    });
  });
}

executeQuery(querystring).then((rown) => {
// do stuff here with rows
});
```

if you need this in a loop, you can do

```
const allPromises= [];
for (let i = 0; i < loopLength; i+=1) {
  allPromises.push(executeQuery(querystring));
}
Promise.all(allPromises).then((result) => {
  // code here
}
```

Comment: The problem is, if I need to put the above function inside a loop, it will give me unexpected results due to asynchronous nature. Is there a way to let things happen in a particular order, when working inside a loop

Comment: you can use `Promise.all`. Updated the cide